# Slow Firebase Firestore cold starts in Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

On a cold start (after deploying or after 3hrs) the function to request a document from Firestore takes an incredible amount of time which is different to when it's used rapidly.

Cold Start:

```
Function execution took 4593 ms, finished with status code: 200
```

Rapid fire (me sending using the same function over and over):

```
Function execution took 437 ms, finished with status code: 200
```

My code for getting the documents is quite simple:

```
function getWorkspaceDocument(teamSpaceId) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var teamRef = db.instance.collection('teams').doc(teamSpaceId);
        teamRef.get().then(doc => {
            if (doc.exists) {
                resolve(doc.data());
                return;
            }
            else {
                reject(new Error("Document cant be found"));
                return;
            }
        }).catch(error => {
            reject(new Error("Document cant be found"));
        });
    });
}
```

I'm trying to make a Slack bot and the slow returns on Firebase Firestore throw time outs in Slacks API. Is there a way on Firebase to stop cold starts from happening and letting it persist through out?

Comment: Are you launching your firestore functions from the right geographical location ?? *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the cloud function needs to start a new instance your cold start time seems normal. This is one drawback of a serverless function.

I think there is a problem with your implementation. Could you show more details?

Here is a nice little video about this topic:
https://youtu.be/v3eG9xpzNXM

Answer (score 1):

*firebaser here*

We actually just [released a new `preferRest` API](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/admin/node#cloud-firestore_1) that should considerably improve the cold start times for Cloud Functions that use Firestore. The documentation for it is not very complete, but you can enable the feature with:

```
import { initializeFirestore } 
    from 'firebase-admin/firestore';

const app = initializeApp();
const firestore = initializeFirestore(app, 
                        { preferRest: true }); // 

firestore.collection(...);
```

With `preferRest: true` the Firestore Admin SDK uses the REST transport layer by default, and it then only loads and uses the gRPC libraries when it encounters an operation that needs them.

Since the gRPC libraries are quite big and the only operation that requires gRPC is creating a snapshot listener, this should reduce the cold start times for most Cloud Functions implementations significantly.

I haven't had a chance to test this myself yet and there are still some known issues, so YMMV and I'd love to hear specifics on what performance change you see from this.

Also see:

- the written [release note about this option](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/admin/node#cloud-firestore_1)
- the Release Notes [video where this is mentioned](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9nkAGR5Qe2A&t=45s)

Answer (score 0):

Another thing I would suggest checking is the amount of memory allocated to a particular function. Each level selected increases non only the RAM, but the CPU frequency as well (and the costs, be careful and don't forget about the [pricing calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator)!). There is a direct dependency between the package size of your function and the cold-start (source: https://mikhail.io/serverless/coldstarts/gcp/).

I can see that you are using the Firestore admin package, which is not considered to be lightweight (source: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/238). Thus, 128MB configuration might not be enough.

For our project increasing the RAM from 128MB to 512MB decreased the cold boot 10x from 20 seconds to 2.5seconds on average. Be sure not to overlook this in case you have several dependencies (7 in our case).